# TimeExhausted Error when calling contract

Tags: web3.py

When I am calling upload_data, everything passes smoothly, but w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt takes forever, and shows following error.

```
def upload_data(self, api_key, api_data):

    nonce = self.w3.eth.getTransactionCount(self.address)

    print("Building Transaction...")

    upload_data_tx = self.data_bridge.functions.uploadData(
        api_key, api_data
    ).buildTransaction(
        {"chainId": self.chain_id, "from": self.address, "nonce": nonce + 1}
    )

    print("Signing Transaction...")

    signed_upload_data_tx = self.w3.eth.account.sign_transaction(
        upload_data_tx, private_key=self.private_key
    )

    print("Sending Transaction...")

    tx_hash = self.w3.eth.send_raw_transaction(
        signed_upload_data_tx.rawTransaction,
    )
    print("Finalizing Transation...")
    receipt = self.w3.eth.wait_for_transaction_receipt(tx_hash)
    return receipt



    raise TimeExhausted(
web3.exceptions.TimeExhausted: Transaction HexBytes('0x21e9a0c358f0caaecd88cfe66ad8ce4856ace7252659d1cf4be869251311b0d2') is not in the chain after 120 seconds
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Did you get this resolved? I'm running into the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

[Per the docs](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/web3.eth.html), the default wait time for `wait_for_transaction_receipt()` is 120 seconds. Your script will wait for the transaction for the default time and if it doesn't see your transaction in a mined block within that time, it will throw this `TimeExhausted` exception.

One idea is you could pass an argument in seconds to wait longer than the default 120, say `timeout=600` for 10 minutes.

Another idea: you could increase the gas you are paying in effort to get your transaction included by the miners faster than it is. Hope this helps.